# constructor with parameters

Tags: constructor, default

- A constructor with an integer parameter (constructs an SDL containing that integer only.
- A default constructor (constructs an empty SDL)

I wrote these like that;

```
doublylinkedlist::doublylinkedlist(){
head=NULL;
tail=NULL;
}

//***********************************************************************************************
//A constructor with an integer parameter (constructs an SDL containing that integer only).     *
//***********************************************************************************************
doublylinkedlist::doublylinkedlist(int number){

    head->num =number;
    tail=head;
}
```

but there is an error window about unhandled exception access violation writing location at

```
head->num=number;
```

line. Where is the problem ? and also this is my header file if you want to take a look :

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef _HW3_H
#define _HW3_H

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int num;
    node * left;
    node * right;

    node::node(){}
    node::node(const int &integer, node *pointer, node *ptr):num(integer),left(pointer),right(ptr){}
};

class doublylinkedlist
{
private:
    node *head;
    node *tail;
    int size;

public:
    doublylinkedlist();
    doublylinkedlist(int);
    doublylinkedlist(const doublylinkedlist &);
    ~doublylinkedlist();
    node* clone() const;
    node *remove() const;
    node *mergedlists(const doublylinkedlist &);

    const doublylinkedlist & operator+(const doublylinkedlist &);
    const doublylinkedlist & operator=(const doublylinkedlist &);

};

#endif
```

Comment: In that constructor, you're setting a value in the object pointed to by `head`. Ask yourself: where is that? Did I ever cause `head` to point to *anything* at all? Have I allocated a `head` node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your head pointer first with a pointer to a node object:

```
doublylinkedlist::doublylinkedlist(int number)
:   head(new node())
{
    head->num =number;
    tail=head;
}
```

The error occoured, because there was no node object "behind" the pointer